# Multiple prototype cells in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView, but I would like the cells to look differently depending on the section. Specifically, I would like section 0 and one to have a UIStepper on the right side of the cell.

In IB, the UITableView has two prototype cells. In the first one, I added the UIStepper, and the second one I left as the default (blank). I gave the stepper UITableViewCell the identifier "StepperCell" (in IB), and the non-stepper cell the identifier "Cell".

Now, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am checking the section number and then applying the appropriate reuse identifier like so:

```
static NSString *stepper = @"StepperCell";
static NSString *normal = @"Cell";
NSString *identifier = normal;
NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

if (section == 0 || section == 1) 
{
    identifier = stepper;
}

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: identifier];
```

I thought that this might work as I intend it to, but it leaves all cells as the default, blank cell. Is there a way to do what I described, without programmatically adding a UIStepper?

edit - it looks like the UIStepper is not showing because the accessory view is set to None in IB. Is there a way to make the UIStepper my accessory view in IB, rather than the default choices (detail disclosure, etc)?

Comment: your code looks ok, have you debugged it through to see if section ever gets 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, it does get 0 and 1... like I said in the edit, the problem is that there is no accessory view. If I change the cell's accessory view to detail disclosure, for example, the UIStepper becomes visible (partially, it is behind the detail disclosure button)

Comment: Add it to the content view not the accessory view.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in IB? I do not have any problem with doing it programmatically. I do not see a way to add a UIStepper to the content view of a prototype cell.

Answer (score 1):

I can add UIStepper to the prototype cell in my IB without any problem.

Make sure not to forget about setting `Style` to `Custom` in the "*Attributes inspector*" of the prototype cell in your IB.